# Can I make Xcode recognize LLDB breakpoints I created outside of Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode5, lldb

If I create a breakpoint using Xcode's Breakpoint Navigator (CMD-7), and then invoke the LLDB debugger, I can see those breakpoints in the debugger using the LLDB command `breakpoints list`. However, if I create a breakpoint using the lldb debugger directly, for instance by doing `breakpoint set --name 'viewDidLoad'`, then I do not see  the new breakpoint reflected in Xcode. Similarly, if I enable/disable breakpoints from LLDB directly, this is not 
reflected in Xcode.

In other words, it seems like the Xcode does not see LLDB breakpoints it did not create. Xcode is not a faithful interface into LLDB.

This seems quite busted. Is there a way to tell Xcode to refresh its understanding of LLDB, so that it picks changes to LLDB's breakpoint configurations which I made directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a way to do this yet.  If you are able to do so, please file a bug about this at bugreporter.apple.com.  The bug will get duped, but bugs are also votes for features and this one hasn't gotten done yet because so far there's always been something more important in front of it on the stack.